# In what header is copy_from_user() declared?

Tags: linux-kernel, header-files

Can anyone please help me with getting the proper header files needed for the `copy_from_user` method?

I found a few of the include headers I need, but my compiler keeps saying that they are not found. I am running CentOS on my machine. I have tried `yum` installing various kernel-headers and devel packages but still no luck.

Is there a special segment I need to add in my `gcc` command?  Everything I find on the Internet only tells me how to use the method but not actually how I can get access to it in the first place.

Comment: Are you coding a kernel module? If you do, you'll need some specific way to compile it....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you're developing a kernel module, because outside of it trying to use `copy_from_user` wouldn't make sense. Either way, in the kernel use:

```
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
```

**Edit**: if *building* a kernel module is what you want, you may want to look at this [Hello World Linux Kernel Module](https://web.archive.org/web/20120911090932/http://www.prabusurendra.com/tutors/lt2/lt2.html). Specifically the makefile portion may be of interest to you (search for `obj-m`).

Comment: I am still learning as I go so don't be afraid to explain it to me like i'm 5.  I noticed that include statement but that and "asm/uaccess.h" both tell me that they can't be found after trying to compile.  Is developing a kernel module a different process than simply trying to compile a programname.c file? I am writing a program that uses somebody elses header files/methods.  They are storing a vital piece of information as "char __user *buf".  I am trying to use that buffer and store it in a linked list to use later but since it's a pointer, I can't get it to save multiple different buffers.

Comment: Yes, developing a kernel module is very different from developing a regular application. One of the primary reasons for developing a kernel module is to write a device driver (to control real hardware with). If you're trying to develop a regular application (i.e. one with a `main()` function) you shouldn't expect to be able to use code that uses `copy_from_user` or `__user` annotated pointers as-is.